# Can you think of any exceptions to the following rules?

Tags: english, language

A. The word ‘the’ is not used with the names of people.

B. The past simple form of the verb is only used to describe finished events or states.

C. The word ‘some’ is used in statements; the word ‘any’ in negatives and questions.

D. The word ‘can’ (modal verb) is only used to express ability.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a puzzle.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/303696/can-you-think-of-any-exceptions-to-the-following-rules

Comment: @friedemann_bach note that the question you linked is asked by the OP of this question.

Comment: I noted, just thought it was of interest.

Comment: a modal verb by definition implies ability, so  `D` is kind of pointless. If you're using another form of 'can', it's not a modal verb and doesn't matter

Answer (score 2):

A. ‘the’ is not used with the names of people.

> "The Donald" (for Donald Trump)

B. The past simple form of the verb is used to describe finished events or states.

C. ‘some’ is used in statements; ‘any’ in negatives and questions.

> He didn't manage to get some (with the phrase "to get some")

D. ‘can’ (modal verb) is used to express ability.